# AJAX failure with Safari browser

Tags: ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, safari

Below is my code related to AJAX call. I am using AngularJS to call the service.

In Safari browser sometimes the AJAX call is getting failed and going to error block. When I tried to see the Content.Length using HTTPRequest in Global.asax page, it seems to be 0. Also Content.Length is 0 for every AJAX call which is failed. I am facing the same problem when I tried to access it on iPad.

```
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: getModifiedURL(userInfo.URL + '/FilterDataService.svc/GetFilters'),
                data: { inputFilters: JSON.stringify(prm) },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $("#ajaxLoader,#ajaxBlocker").hide();
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                setAckMessageWithTime("Operation failed", 3000);
                $("#ajaxLoader,#ajaxBlocker").hide();
            });
            return promise;
```

I am using Safari 5.1.7(7534.57.2) version, AngularJS and Bootstrap in my application.

Here is the error it throws.

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetFilters'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).'. See server logs for more details.** The exception stack trace is:

\r\n

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)